# RocketChat A notice of push of ios does not come

Tags: ios

version:0.55.1

A notice of push of ios does not come
but,The notice of the disk top arrives.

```
■Notice test log
[34mI20170427-09:27:04.021(0) rocketchat_logger rocketchat_logger.js:377 
[34mMeteor ➔ method push_test -> userId: QHBp4XvLTkEsyNvZ4 , arguments:  {}
```